# Нет перевода текста на заблокированных вопросах

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, заблокированные-вопросы

[Текущие заблокированные вопросы на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3A1) содержат в плашке под телом вопроса следующий текст:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is
>   not considered a good, on-topic question for this site so please do
>   not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This
>   question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. See the
>   справка for guidance on writing a good question.

Comment: Что-то сборка была, а переводы не подхватились.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ впрочем, ничего нового   (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @αλεχολυτ https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331548/260198

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я совсем запутался. Николай говорил, что там всё на автомате, а gbianchi [пишет](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331548/when-exactly-are-translations-deployed#comment1081438_331548), что всё равно нужно дёрнуть.

Comment: Пути SOшные неисповедимы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взял за базу старый вариант с транзифекса. Получилось [так](https://ru.traducir.win/string/12746):

> Этот вопрос сохранили по причине его исторической важности, но **он не расценивается как хороший вопрос по теме, соответствующей специфике сайта**, 
>   поэтому просим вас не рассматривать его как подтверждение вашей возможности публиковать аналогичные вопросы. Этот вопрос и ответы на него заморожены, их невозможно изменить. См. [help/on-topic] как руководство для написания хорошего вопроса.

На сайте после подкачки и пересборки.